# How can Forms Authentication redirect to Login.aspx in the same browser session?

Tags: asp.net, forms, session, redirect, authentication

When I click on my Login link it takes me to the Login.aspx page in the same browser session as expected.

But when I click on a page the user needs to be authenticated to see, it redirects to the login.aspx page in a new browswer tab. Thus it now has two tabs open.

Anybody know how to stop this behavior? I would like the app to switch to the login.aspx page in the same session.

- Using asp.net 3.5
- c#
- Browser is Firefox

Any help would be appreciated

Victor D.

Comment: How does the link to this authenticated page look like? Make sure it doesn't have the `target="_blank"` attribute.

Comment: You solved it!

Sweet.. Thank you very much. I had done an extensive google search and couldn't find the answer.